# Facebook onCompleted is called twice

Tags: android, facebook

I did the following:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }        
    uiHelper.onResume();
}
```

and

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        makeMeRequest(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {

    }
}
```

and

```
private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (user != null) {
                    log.d("creating fragment");  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    //creating a fragment when the request is complete
                    .....
                }                    
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {

            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Please read the comment of the first code clause: as suggested by Facebook, that code works because without it, the fragment is not created in certain scenarios even though I'm logged in, but with this code, onCompleted is called twice and I get an exception. see my logging in the 3rd code clause: log.d("creating fragment") - I see it twice before the exception occurred.

Any idea what am I missing?
p.s.: I have a main activity that calls a fragment where the user can login to facebook

Answer (score 0):

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
    onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
}
```

don't use above code  in `onresume()`,

Activity normally called first `oncreate() and then onresume()`.so that it's called twice.

please check it.

Comment: Thanks, Facebook recommends to add this to onResume for when the app is opened from a shortcut after I'm already logged in (this is exactly what happens to me). Nothing is being called on onCreate.

Comment: `UiLifecycleHelper` to track the session and trigger a session state change listener.so that `Session.StatusCallback()` called by uilifecycle helper.

Comment: use same as  the facebook login flow      https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate